# Can I control where default focus is for an application?

Tags: window, focus

When I **start** some app I want to **control were focus is**(for **example** if I start **firefox** I want focus to be for example on **address bar**).

P.S. *Im not looking for Firefox plugin*, I just wonder if there is app for that.

Comment: I think that is application defined behavior and you will not be able to change it.

Comment: I could write script in AutoHotKey to do that, but I hoped that in Linux there is some magic tool for that(I feel that most app here do the focus wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that I would need to write script in tools like AutoHotKey(its a windows tools, but there are linux # counterpart)